# How do I perform an operation on every other character on a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I capitalize only a string's even letters?

I've tried:

```
str = "apples"; str.capitalize
```

Comment: Please show the code you've written showing you've attempted to find a solution.

Comment: str = "apples"; str.capitalize

Answer (score 3):

```
"abcdefgh".gsub /..?/, &:capitalize
=> "AbCdEfGh"

"abcdefgh".gsub /(?!^)..?/, &:capitalize
=> "aBcDeFgH"
```

Use `string.gsub!` instead of `string.gsub` if you want to modify your original string.

Answer (score 0):

```
string.scan(/..?/).map(&:capitalize) * ''
```

Comment: Why not `.join` instead of `* ''`?

Comment: because it's longer. Same thing either way.